# How to Insert columns into multiple CSV files in a single directory using powershell

Tags: powershell, csv

Hello Big Thanks to the mjolinor for this really fast and efficient code. This code adds Column 5 and Column 6 (with Header5 and Header6) at the end of each file. Now I would like to make "small?" change to this code and add those 2 columns Before Header1.(In a First column would be name of the file, second column is always 0 and then rest of the data).
Hopefully only a small change is needed, because I really like how fast Mjolinor's code do its job (I have around 3000 files in a single directory).

```
$InputFolder = 'c:\SomeFolder'
$OutputFolder = 'c:\SomeOtherFolder'

Get-ChildItem $InputFolder -Filter *.* |
where {-not $_.psiscontainer} |
foreach {
$FileName = $_.Name
$BaseName = $_.Basename
$data = Get-Content $_ -ReadCount 0
"$($data[0]),Header5,Header6" | Set-Content $OutputFolder\$FileName
$data[1..($data.Length -1)] -replace '$',",0,$BaseName" | 
Add-Content $OutputFolder\$FileName
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
$InputFolder = 'c:\SomeFolder'
$OutputFolder = 'c:\SomeOtherFolder'

Get-ChildItem $InputFolder -Filter *.* |
where {-not $_.psiscontainer} |
foreach {
$FileName = $_.Name
$BaseName = $_.Basename
$data = Get-Content $_ -ReadCount 0
"Header6,Header5,$($data[0])" | Set-Content $OutputFolder\$FileName
$data[1..($data.Length -1)] -replace '^',"$BaseName,0," | 
Add-Content $OutputFolder\$FileName
}
```